# Including desired rank in a cover letter for an open-rank faculty position?

Tags: job-search, tenure-track

I'm an assistant professor in my fifth year and have decided to go on the job market this year.  Obviously I prefer tenured positions to pre-tenure positions, but I'm interested in either one.  Would it be weird to leave this ambiguous in a cover letter, that is, to simply say "I am applying for a position in your department" without specifying the rank?  It  seems to me that if I say I'm applying for an associate position, then some departments might say "oh, she's not ready for an associate position, too bad, we would have hired her at the assistant level", whereas, if I apply at the assistant level, I might be passing up opportunities for a tenured position.

Comment: I've been on faculty recruiting committees for well over a decade, and I have **never** read a cover letter.

Comment: If I head an application without cover letter on the table I **never** read the application.

Comment: @Dirk I think JeffE is referring to the fact that for many academic positions, the cover letter serves solely as an administrative tool so the application gets routed to the proper committee (e.g., "I am applying for the open tenure-track assistant professor position in the C.S. department" is really about the only important part of the letter). That said, in at least one case I found out that a comment I made in my cover letter about previous teaching experience was the reason the department chair flagged my application, and I subsequently got the job.

Comment: I also do not read applications in which the cover letter does not say anything more than "I am applying for the position...". I expect that the applicant is able to express why the position is interesting for him and why I should be interested in him.

Comment: @Dirk Interesting. Guidance I've been given for faculty positions has been, "Don't waste your time discussing the position in the cover letter." This may not be the best guidance in the world, but I'm not sure I agree that the cover letter is a particularly good place (for an academic position) to discuss why the position is interesting. Certainly if there is something unique that should be mentioned, I would mention it, but I wouldn't rely on the cover letter to discuss important information germane to the application.

Comment: I should add that I am in the German academic system (for which the application process for faculty positions is at least slightly different, e.g. you don't need to add recommendation letters with the application (but in a later phase)).

Comment: @Dirk: That's what research and teaching statements, which all US academic job applications require, are for.  The cover letter is simply redundant.  Moreover, many web-based application systems don't even give you a way to upload a cover letter.

Comment: @JeffE: Right. In Germany it is not standard to have a research and teaching statements. However, I have often seen people who have general teaching and research statements on their homepage and then an additional cover letter could illustrate why the specific position is interesting for the specific candidate.

Comment: @JeffE: I'm  not sure your experience is universal.  I've had interviews where the interviewer brought up things I'd mentioned in my cover letter (and not elsewhere), so at least some people do read them.  I agree that they are not a very important piece of an application, but in some cases you want to include information that isn't appropriate anywhere else.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect this is one of these questions where there is no truly "correct answer" as you can't predict what's going on in any given search committee, but I think you're unlikely to do any damage by leaving it open.  At least my understanding of these things is that a department would rather hire you w/o tenure (note that this is not quite the same as the associate/assistant distinction) as it is less of a headache with the administration; you'll get tenure if they really want you, and don't think they'll get you otherwise.  I don't think it will matter much what you wrote in your cover letter.  Concentrate on making them want you, and then worry about what they have to do to get you.